# Keepass to ssh to a second server

Tags: ssh, keepass

How do I setup keepass to ssh to a second server once in the ssh session? 
For eg, I double click the keepass entry which logs me into serverA. 
 I can only reach serverB from serverA, so I want keepass to automatically type something like: 
`ssh user@serverB` ...once it is logged onto serverA. (Optionally, if it auto supplied the password to this as well, it would be great, but not necessary).

We make use of URL overrides, so our typical URL entry looks like: 
`ssh://xx.xx.xx.xx`

Comment: The url override is set to call up PuTTY.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it appears I can get this done mostly with the Auto-type feature in Keepass, which allows me to define keystrokes it can send.
To make it send a keystroke, I just press ctrl+alt+a.
It's an unwanted step, but better than typing the whole string every time.
It's all explained here: http://keepass.info/help/base/autotype.html